# serverless service not responding as expected

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Doing following steps in a openshift sandbox:

```
kn service create event-display-kn --image danielon30/quarkus-serverless:latest
oc label ksvc event-display-kn networking.knative.dev/visibility=cluster-local
```

I get a service running as expected with a local routing.

so curling is fine

```
$ curl -v http://event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev.svc.cluster.local
* Rebuilt URL to: http://event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev.svc.cluster.local/
*   Trying 172.30.125.86...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev.svc.cluster.local (172.30.125.86) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev.svc.cluster.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< accept-ranges: bytes
< cache-control: public, max-age=86400
< content-length: 3940
< content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 10:50:52 GMT
< last-modified: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 10:50:26 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 3
< server: envoy
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>quarkus-knative - 1.0-SNAPSHOT</title>
    <style>
```

also fine

```
$ curl -v  http://event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev
* Rebuilt URL to: http://event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev/
*   Trying 172.30.125.86...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev (172.30.125.86) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: event-display-kn.gratinierer-dev
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< accept-ranges: bytes
< cache-control: public, max-age=86400
< content-length: 3940
< content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 10:49:05 GMT
< last-modified: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 10:49:05 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1369
< server: envoy
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

but here it ends

```
bash-4.4 ~ $ curl -v http://event-display-kn                
* Rebuilt URL to: event-display-kn/
*   Trying 172.30.125.86...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to event-display-kn (172.30.125.86) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: event-display-kn
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 10:45:24 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host event-display-kn left intact
```

strage here:  the host is resolved and an 404 returns, but who answeres this call?
Why do we get here different behaviours (on the same IP and port)?